# Can not access Ubuntu Server with SSH after allowing firewall?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I tried to install an FTP server with vsftpd on our server and ran the command sudo ufw allow ftp. After rebooting the server, I can not access it anymore.

When I ping the IP, I still get feedback. With putty I get a "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" error after doing that.

What happened here I how can I access the server again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very likely that you set up `ufw` with a default policy that denies all incoming traffic. This is commonly suggested, as it's a "secure by default" setting that only permits what you explicitly allowed. It's also mentioned in guides [like this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04).

So if you ran:

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw allow ftp
```

followed by a `ufw enable` (or `reload`), then you would immediately lose access to the server via SSH, since incoming connections on port 22 (the SSH default) would not be allowed.

The only way to get access to the server now is to physically connect a keyboard and a monitor, enter a root shell, and temporarily disable `ufw`, or, even better, run `ufw allow ssh` and `ufw reload` to allow SSH access from the outside.

If your server is hosted by a provider, you need to connect via the provider's backend. All providers should give you access to an emergency console for these purposes.

If you have no physical access and your server provider does not offer emergency console access, you need to make a custom support request to get staff to change the firewall settings.

Comment: thank you very much, this really sucks :-(